# property of $\sigma$ finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathit{M}:=\{\mu \ on \ (\mathbb R,\mathit B)|\sigma-finite,\mu(-\infty,0]<\infty\}$, during I hear a lecture, for $\mu\in M,x>0$,  $\mu(-\infty,x]=\mu(-\infty,0]+\mu(0,x]<\infty$, It is clear $\mu(-\infty,0]<\infty$, but why the $\sigma$ finite of $\mu$ imply $\mu(0,x]<\infty$?
here $B$ is borel set.

Comment: Let $\mu ( \mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1) = 0$ and let $\mu (0,x] = {1 \over 1-x}$ for $x \in (0,1)$. Let $X_m = ( \mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1) ) \cup (0,1-{1 \over m})$, and note that $\mu X_m< \infty$, and $\cup_m X_m = \mathbb{R}^n$.